# VMware Vsphere Monitoring and Alerting Network Outage

Tags: networking, vmware-vsphere, vmware-server, vsphere-client

I am trying to set up an alert to email out when any of our VMs lose network connectivity. I'm trying the following settings but I do not get any alerts when I kill the network connection.

- Alarm Type: Virtual Machine

  - Monitor for specific events occurring on this suybject...
- Trigger: VM No Network Access
- Status: Alert

I've tried the same settings with a different event (such as power on and power off) and I get an email alert every time. But, with network access I get nothing. For testing, I've reset the IP (so there is no network activity), I've disabled the NIC, and I've tried turning the NIC off in the VMware settings.

Nothing is alerting? Essentially, I jut want an email when any of my VMs happen to lose Internet access for any reason.

I would think there would be a hidden command similar to the one for the esxi linkstate down, as well (esx.problem.net.vmnic.linkstate.down).  But, I've not been able to find one.

Thanks for any assistance.

Another note: I've also tried using different Ethernet Adapter drivers, with no luck.

Comment: Why would a VM lose connectivity?

Comment: We are not sure yet.  But it happens periodically.  We are trying to catch it when it does happen.  Part of the reason we want the alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decided to just use Veeam ONE.  Their free version offers enough data and monitoring.

Seems that network monitoring is a shortfall of VMware.

Comment: Only just spotted this question - did you try doing this via a host vswitch port alert - that's how ours are setup, not via individual VMs but via the hosts themselves and it works great - actually we use SNMP not mail but they do work.

Comment: @Chopper3 Monitoring on the host notifies you of individual VMs going offline?  I'll definitely look into that.  Thanks.